# Can't connect remotely to MySQL cPanel database

Tags: mysql, node.js, cpanel

I can't connect remotely from Nodejs to a MySQL database from a domain. I've searched a lot, my ip is listed in the host list, and I've also checked the MySQL variables and the bind-address is set to *.
And, also, does anyone know why when I try to add a new host for remote mysql connections it says that the % wildcard is not allowed?

With another domain it works just fine.

Please help me figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: are you able to provide any more details?

Comment: @Refineo I get connection timed out, but my ip is added to allowed hosts in remote mysql in cpanel, but still, the same error, without other details. Also the credentials I use to connect, are correct, double checked them...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the port is open from remote by using MySQL workbench or other clients. You can also use telnet in the command line:

```
telnet {database ip} 3306
```

If you got a **timeout**, It seems there is a Firewall or Mysql config not listening remote IPs so call your ISP or hosting provider and ask them for open access.
But if you got "**access denied**" message or telnet connection was successful, we have something wrong in MySQL user privilege.